# mysqldump: Error: 'Can't create/write to file

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

Can't create temporary files on `/var/tmp`.

```
mysqldump: Error: 'Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/mysql.k6NKGk/#sql_5dc_2.MAI' (Errcode: 2)' when trying to dump tablespaces
```

On my OS.

```
 id mysql
uid=60(mysql) gid=105(mysql) groups=105(mysql)

ls -l /var/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root  72 oct 24 16:43 tmp
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you can change the owner with

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/tmp
```

Check to see if there is a `[mysqldump]` header in `/etc/my.cnf`. It may look like this:

```
[mysqldump]
tmpdir=/var/tmp
```

or perhaps under the `[mysqld]` header

```
[mysqldump]
tmpdir=/var/tmp
```

Try commenting it out and trying mysqldump again.

Comment: the ownership is not a good practice, but commenting out the tmp and chanchind de tmpdir did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/var/tmp/mysql.k6NKGk/` may have been removed by `systemd-tmpfiles` (or `tmpwatch`) if there were no activity since a while.

A service restart is a way to work-around the issue.

Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997012/mysql-cant-create-write-to-file-tmp-sql-3c6-0-myi-errcode-2-what-does for details or other possible sources like SELinux.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, I fixed it by changing the `tmpdir` path.

You can change it to whatever you like, just set the permission for that folder correctly ("write" for all or just for the `mysql` user).